# How can I save the value of "year", "month" and "day" of DatePickerDialog into realm database?

Tags: datepickerdialog

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

```
    var cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    var year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    var month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    var day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"for test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    **btn_cal.setOnClickListener {
        val pickdate = DatePickerDialog(
                requireContext(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            view,  y: Int, m: Int, d: Int ->
            text_cal.setText("${y}년 ${m + 1}월 ${d}일")
        }, year, month, day
        )
        pickdate.show()
    }**


    navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    btn_home01.setOnClickListener {
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_fragment_one_to_fragment_home)
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to have a Realm object that has property or properties that represent that data. You could use a single date property - those are queryable and sortable so it's probably the way to go. It's a good idea to tag questions with your coding language and also include the code you've attempted so we can understand where you're stuck. Please update your question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to add a Realm object after i make sure that "year","month" and "day" have new values. I checked with Toast after btn_cal, but those var still have only current date and dosen't show picked date.

Comment: You would not not add a Realm object after. You would create a Realm object model as part of your application that has those properties. Then when you want to populate it, instantiate the model in code and add the data to it you want. Then save it to realm using a realm.write. If you are asking about how to work with a datepicker, that's unrelated to Realm and the Realm tag should be removed as it doesn't apply to the question about datepicker.